# Storage size not know with gnu99 only on Windows but not Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, signals, sigaction

I am writing code in C using `sigaction`. Compiling using minGW on Windows.
I noticed that c99 doesn't support `sigaction` so I used the flag `-std=gnu99` when compiling.
Why does it give me the error message "storage size of 'newact' isn't known
" only on Windows but not on Linux? 
FYI `newact` is a `struct sigaction`

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: The [`sigaction` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) and the `sigaction` structure from [the `signal.h` header file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) is a POSIX standard. They don't exist on non-POSIX systems (like Windows), only on POSIX systems (like Linux, macOS and the BSD variants). And no it's not in the C standard, or GCC extensions, it's a strict platform (operating system) problem.